# CSS: how to dynamically grow/shrink an HTML table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, css

I have a HTML like so:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>colA heading</th>
    <th>colb heading</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>colA content</td>
    <td>colb content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>colC heading</th>
    <th>colD heading</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>colC content</td>
    <td>colC content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That products the following output:

**colA heading     colB heading**
colA content        colB content
**colC heading     colD heading**
colC content        colD content

what I want to do is detect using presumably JavaScript, if the page is wide enough, dynamically change my table look like so:

**colA heading     colB heading     colC heading     colD heading**
colA content        colB content             colC content        colD content

How can I do that using HTML (and JavaScript/CSS if need be)?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, would you be okay with A, B and C on one line, and D on the next?  Or do A/B and C/D have to be package deals?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, It's either 1) Have A & B on one line and C & D on another line, or 2) Have A, B, C & D all on one line.  So no, ABC on one line and D on other would not work ... not would A on one line and BCD on another

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this is achievable by splitting your table into two tables, like so:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .bigBox {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            float: left;
            clear: right;
            display: inline;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="bigBox">
        <tr>
            <th>colA heading</th>
            <th>colb heading</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>colA content</td>
            <td>colb content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="bigBox">
        <tr>
            <th>colC heading</th>
            <th>colD heading</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>colC content</td>
            <td>colC content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The border is for ease of testing only.  All you have to do to test is set the contents of one of the cells to something like "colb headingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg."

Comment: Good answer, but the drawback is that semantically, it's no longer a single table, but that might not be a problem in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

How would you determine that the table should be able to fit in one table?

Are you starting from two tables, going to one table, or from one -> 2?

It would be easiest to either start with one table, and if the scrollbars are active then do something like the following tiny snippet. You should use firebug, in firefox, to examine the dom attributes of the table, to determine the properties to use.

```
var tableelem = document.createElement('table');
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
for(var t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
  var trow = document.createElement('tr');
  var tdata = document.createElement('td');
  tdata.appendChild(document.createTextNode('header'));
  thead.appendChild(trow);
}
tableelem.appendChild(thead);
```

You will need to use `document.getElementById` to get the table you will be pulling from, and then the header will be in `table.rows[0]`, so you can parse the cells in that row and get the values where I put *header* above.

You will then need to add the `tableelem` to the div using the `appendChild` function.